# Looping over a Matlab structure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, structure

I am currently processing a bunch of files that I have imported into a structure, but have hit a bump in the road while trying to loop over the data.

First of all, here is my structure:

1. Ice

   1.1 az160, az240, az300...

   ```
   1.1.2 zen15, zen30,zen45... 

       1.1.2.1 Data

       1.1.2.2 Textdata
   ```

I am trying to extract a value from each "textdata" cell array and use it to divide a column in data of the same structure. To do so, I am looping through the structure in the following way:

```
az_names = fieldnames(ice)

for m = 1:numel(az_names)

  snames = fieldnames(ice.(az_names{m}))

  for k = 1:numel(snames)

    inttime = strrep(ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).textdata(9,1), 'Integration > Time (usec): ','');
    inttime = strrep(inttime, ' (USB2+E00040)','');
    integration = cellfun(@str2num,inttime)

line 17    ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data(:,4) = ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data(:,3)/integration

   end
end
```

I get the following error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Edit: Matlab gives me the error at line 17. If I run the code up to "integration" and also write:

> ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data(:,4)

I don't get a problem, Matlab prints to screen the right number and the data column.

I thought this would loop through each field in the structure and do the operation (dividing a column of values by a number), but I seem to be missing a point here. Can anybody see my mistake?

Regards,

Comment: On which line does that error occur? Where are the matrix dimensions being exceeded?

Comment: Maybe you should mark on your code where's the line that gives you this error.

Comment: Along with providing the entire error (which would be super helpful and you should do this always) so we know where the error is, you can use `dbstop if error` to enter the debugger when an error occurs so you can investigate the values of your variables. See the documentation for [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error occurs when you try to execute this fragment:

```
ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data(:,4)
```

Then the cause is quite simple.

The variables `m` and `k` seem to be handled properly (due to the `numel` in the loop they should never be too big), meaning that the 4 is simply too big.

Check

```
ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data(:,4)
```

Or even more directly

```
size(ice.(az_names{m}).(snames{k}).data)
```

And you should find that the second element of the size is less than 4.

---

On second thought, this fragment works:

```
a.b=1;
a.b(:,4)=1
```

So I suspect that the error occurs when trying to read in this part:

```
ice.(az_names{m}). (snames{k}).data(:,3)
```

Meaning that the second element of the size should even be less than 3.

Also I would recommend removing the space.

Comment: Originally "data" has three columns, and I am trying to assign the result of the division to a forth column (do I need to preallocate?). The space was a typo in the question, sorry.

Comment: Okay, one of my "data" only has 2 columns. So now I need to find which one, but I think this will repair this error!